# Declare a public static variable with custom logic

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, static

I have the below class:

```
public class Actionkeywords{

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void openBrowser(String object, String data) {
                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void mobilesetup{
        driver=new AndroidDriver();
    }
}
```

Here, I need to have a custom logic to use the same name driver for both the variable.
Something like this:

```
if(automationtype.equalignorecase("Mobile"))
    Android driver=new AndroidDriver();
else
    Webdriver driver=new WebDriver();
```

Automation type is a string variable which will carry the type of automation. ie, Web automation or mobile automation.

Comment: In short, I need a global variable with name driver. 'driver' will be initialized in separate methods as Webdriver or AndroidDriver.

Answer (score 2):

Just omit the type from the start of the line. Otherwise:

1. you're declaring a local variable;
2. you're declaring it in the scope of the conditional branches, and so can't use it afterwards.

So it would look like:

```
if(automationtype.equalIgnoreCase("Mobile"))
  driver=new AndroidDriver();
else
  driver=new WebDriver();
```

Comment: I need the declaration outside of all the methods. And its a static variable.

Comment: The declaration *is* outside all methods currently; if you mean the *initialization* should be outside of all methods (a rather arbitrary requirement), `public static WebDriver driver = automationtype.equalIgnoreCase("Mobile") ? new AndroidDriver() : new WebDriver();`. Just need to make sure that `automationtype` is correctly initialized first.

Comment: But here left side declares driver as WebDriver instance right?

Comment: It declares that it is a reference to an instance of `WebDriver` or one of its subclasses, just like `Object object = "string";` declares and initializes a reference to an instance of `Object` or one of its subclasses.

Comment: Yea got it. But next challenge is I need to pass parameters with new AndroidDriver() and new WebDriver(). But these parameters can be obtained only from the methods.